# Ruby Syntax Error, unexpected tLABEL

Tags: ruby, syntax, syntax-error

EDIT:

I have created [a package](https://github.com/whotooktwarden/rippled-sign-submit) that is now released on GitHub under a GNU Public License.  Thank you all very much for your help on this issue!

With this portion of script:

```
line = { TransactionType: "Payment",
Account: #{xagate},
Destination: #{destinationAddress},
Amount: {
currency: "TST",
value: "#{destAmount}",
issuer: "rKYHqy2QWbf5WThp7vdJAxTR3WBHKDh9xv"
}
```

I receive this error:

```
syntax error, unexpected tLABEL
Destination: #{destinationAddress},
            ^
```

What is causing this syntax error?  The accepted answer below explains how to fix this error.  As for the Ripple JSON, I discovered that the err29 for the rippled server software is a result of a missing Fee and Sequence field.  If you are also experiencing this issue, the answer is being investigated in this thread:  https://forum.ripple.com/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=15599

Comment: I submitted an edit for your question. The additional details you added about `undefined []` should be submitted as a new question. However, I recommend that you fix _this_ one before moving onto another error.

Comment: Almost every syntax error question that gets posted in [tag:ruby] can be solved by just looking at the syntax coloring of StackOverflow's syntax highlighter. In this case, for example, in the offending line, the `#` is *clearly* highlighted as a comment (light grey), not a string literal (maroon). The sad thing about this is that SO's syntax highlighter is actually pretty stupid, but is still intelligent enough to catch pretty much all syntax errors posted on SO. Which makes me wonder: doesn't it occur to anyone when posting a **syntax** question to look at the **syntax** highlighting?

Comment: Please edit out all the details that **to not relate to the tLABEL issue**!

Comment: Done.  Thank you again for the help!  Within 24 hours of learning Ruby I was able to get an error message that I was expecting could occur with the rest of the script.

Comment: I have created [a package](https://github.com/whotooktwarden/rippled-sign-submit) that is now released on GitHub under a GNU Public License.  Thank you all very much for your help on this issue!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`unexpected tLABEL`, in my experience, means that an expression or block has not ended correctly. Ruby is reading your code as

```
line = { TransactionType: "Payment",
  Account: Destination:  # STOPS HERE from error
```

`line` is a hash that you are making. Hashes follow the formats: `{ key => value }` and `{ key: value }`. Looks like you are following the second format. As you see above, Ruby is reading your code as `{ key: {key: } }` where the value to the second key is missing.

Outside of a string, the `#` symbol tells Ruby "everything from here to end-of-line is a comment." You can easily see this with the StackOverflow syntax highlighter marking Ruby comments as gray.

But inside a string, `#` is used for string interpolation, which appears to be what you are trying to achieve. String interpolation includes *double* quotation marks wrapped around the text, like so: `"Hello, #{planet}"`, where `#{}` is where you place the variable.

This is how you would write your code, using string interpolation:

```
Account: "#{xagate}",
Destination: "#{destinationAddress}",
```

If you look later in your code, you are actually doing this with `line[Amount][value]` (which is `"#{destAmount}"`)

Since your string *only* contains the object interpolated, I would suggest the following instead. First, you can call `to_s` on the object, converting it to a string. If the object was an array, the string would contain the commas and brackets. Second, you can simply do `Account: xagate`. This is *much* simpler, as you can check the value against the variable, instead of a string containing the variable. (One less step to process!)

Finally, as you mentioned in chat, you are new to Ruby. It is standard convention that all objects starting with a capital letter (like `Account`) refer to *classes*, and objects in caps are *constants*. This is not the reason for your error, although it is good practice to start fixing this now... To prevent issues possibly stemming from that.

Comment: That was the issue.  Any idea why I am getting this error?  nxt.rb:14:in `<main>': undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)  Account must be capitalized for the payment JSON to function, could ruby think that this is a class variable?  This is ocurring on line 14 immediately after secret_xagate=ripple["secret"]["xagate"], so is that an issue with using YAML/ripple.yml config file?

Comment: I answered your initial issue that you had asked for in chat. Follow-up issues should be submitted as a new question.

Answer (score 4):

change

```
Account: #{xagate},
Destination: #{destinationAddress},
```

to

```
Account: "#{xagate}",
Destination: "#{destinationAddress}",
```

Double quotes enclose strings which may contain expressions that should be interpolated. These expressions *inside* a string are marked with `#{...}`

Comment: That solved this issue but I received a new error when attempting to run the script:  nxt.rb:14:in `<main>': undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

Comment: @user2984057 as I commented on your question, the new issue should be submitted in a new question/post.